# Filtering a Backbone Collection returns an array of Models

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, underscore.js

Sample Code:

```
this.books = this.getBooksFromDatabase();
this.publishedBooks = this.books.filter(function(book) {
  return book.get("isPublished") === "1";
});
```

Here lies the problem:

this.books.filter, returns an array of the models. I've tried wrapping the array, as such:

```
var publishedBooks = _( this.books.filter(function(book) {
  return book.get("isPublished") === "1";
}))
```

as recommended by this post:
https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/120

But i still can't run things like:
publishedBooks.each(...), or
publishedBooks.get(...)

What am I missing? Is there a way to convert the returned array into a collection?

Answer (score 34):

You could either instantiate a new backbone collection and pass in the array.

```
var myPublishedBooks = new MyBooksCollection(publishedBooks);
```

Or you could refresh your original collection.

```
this.books.refresh(publishedBooks)
```

---

**Note** that the [0.5.0 release in July 2011](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#changelog) renamed `refresh` to `reset`, so you can achieve this in newer versions of Backbone with;

```
this.books.reset(publishedBooks)
```

Comment: Collection#refresh was renamed to Collection#reset http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset

Answer (score 4):

```
var collection = new Backbone.collection(yourArray)
```

Comment: This only works for "vanilla" Backbone Collection. Even with custom Collection one would need to hard-code its definition. The solution above with reset nicely avoids that.

Answer (score 3):

I often do something like this:

```
var collection = new MySpecialCollection([...]);
//And later...
var subset = new collection.constructor(collection.filter(...));
```

This will create an instance of the same type as your original collection, with the filtered models, so you can continue with the collection methods (each, filter, find, pluck, etc).